# Can in-app purchases be "gifted" in the App Store?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, sdk, app-store

Does anyone know if in-app purchase can be gifted? For example, if I want to give a family member free coins in a game, is this possible?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean. Do you mean the purchase of gift vouchers for the app store, or waiving the app fee for selected customers?

Comment: It's not possible now. It would violate Apple's terms: `11.1 Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected.`

Comment: Unclear and closed? Really? I think it's very clear what's being asked and I have the same question. Up voted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iOS SDK has a framework called Store Kit for handling in app purchases. The framework is only for collecting payment. As stated in the iOS Reference Library In App Purchase Programming Guide:

> You must provide any additional
>   functionality, including unlocking
>   built-in features or downloading
>   content from your own servers.

You would have to create the gifting functionality.

---

"Now using the StoreKit is there a way to submit a purchase with someone else's email? and not the current user?" I do not see a way to do this in the SDK.

When user 1 goes to buy an in app product for user 2, you will have to provide a mechanism for user 1 to select user 2. Then process the payment normally with StoreKit for user 1.  Save the transaction on your server (what user 1 bought user 2).  In your app when you check to unlock or download your in app products you will have to check your server for that authorization.

Comment: StoreKit is not *only* for collecting payment. It also keeps track of who's bought what. True, you have to implement unlocking or downloading, but that isn't so open-ended that you could implement "gifting" without some StoreKit support.

Comment: You'll probably only run into problems when trying to gift non-consumable or subscription items. If the gifting is purely for consumable items, it would probably work. See here for what those terms mean: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html

Comment: how do you "gift" an in-app purchase? like how you gift a normal app using the SDK?

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that you wouldn't use Store Kit at all.  Just that "gifting" is not currently part of the framework.

Comment: if I "gift" an in-app item and my friend tries to download it with his account information.. will itunes automatically know that he has already purchased one? I assume so

Comment: Thanks that is clearing things up. Now using the StoreKit is there a way to submit a purchase with someone else's email? and not the current user? this would solve my "gifting" functionality if I can make a purchase using the store kit and pass in the  recipient's email. I unless it was documented in the SDK and I missed it

Comment: Is this still a problem in IOS 11? 

"Starting in iOS 11, you can promote in-app purchases on the App Store" see: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/PromotingIn-AppPurchases/PromotingIn-AppPurchases.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH11-SW8

Answer (score 6):

"Gifting" per say does not exist/work, but there is a way to provide your StoreKit functionality for free to select users.

In **iTunes Connect**, click on **Manage Users**, then **In App Purchase Test User**.

Here, you can add fake itunes accounts, which have the ability to download your StoreKit content for free. I don't believe you are allowed/able to add real email accounts. Don't think I have tried, but I always create bogus accounts and passwords. Literally anything works.

Logout of your account on your iPhone's App Store, go into your app, and purchase the StoreKit product with the fake account and password. This account provides free content on all of your apps. Not just a specific in-app purchase.

As you can see, this methodology is only good for people you REALLY trust. You need to tell people what the account username and password is, and if they tell other people about it, you lose revenue.

IN ESSENCE:

Gifting ?... No.

Free content for bloggers/beta/family ?... Yes.

Comment: It seems that Labelbox has figured out how to use in-app purchase to give away features for free: http://blog.stepcase.com/labelbox-how-we-got-1-million-downloads-in-th  If you tweet about the app they enable a 'secret' in app purchase option which is free. I'm not quite sure how they allow this as Apple's docs say, "In-App Purchase can be offered in both free and paid apps—no free In-App Purchases are available." http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4009

Comment: They are simply triggering a username check on their server. Each user has an account, and if they retweeted, their account was marked with a special flag, which unlocked the In-App purchase in the app. It has absolutely nothing to do with the actual In-App Purchase system.

Comment: I created a IAP test user but it seems that now that the app is live in the store it won't allow you to make a purchase using one.  It wants me to set it up as a real account with CC information, etc.  Anyone know a way around this?

Comment: FWIK test users are restricted to the sandbox environment by design.

Comment: Since the app is distributed through the Distribution certificate and the public doesn't have the developer certificate in their phones/tablets, this option can't be used.

Comment: "Apps may enable gifting of items that are eligible for in-app purchase to others. Such gifts may only be refunded to the original purchaser and may not be exchanged." - 3.1.1 https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/